# Whether there exists some compact manifold whose continuous map must have a fixed point?

Tags: manifolds, fixed-point-theorems, klein-bottle

Whether there is some compact [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold) $M$ such that  $f:M\rightarrow M$ is continuous $\Rightarrow f$ has a fix point.

I mean that any continuous map from $M$ to $M$ must have a fixed point.

I really just guess it. And know nothing about whether it is right or not. Maybe Klein bottle is an example, but I don't know how to prove it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such manifolds exist, even without boundary. For example, $\mathbb{CP}^{2n}$ can be shown to be such a manifold for all $n$ by the [Lefschetz fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem).

With boundary there are simpler examples, such as the disks $D^n$, by the [Brouwer fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem).